# How to remove child in an array in actionscript

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, removechild

How to remove a child in an array in ActionScript 3.0?
Here's my code. I put the child I want to remove in an array called `nailList[]` and put it on gameStage.

```
function makeNails():void
{   
    for (var i=0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        for (var j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            var tempNail = new Nail2(j * C.NAIL_DISTANCE + C.NAIL_START_X,
            i * C.NAIL_DISTANCE + C.NAIL_START_Y);

            nailList.push(tempNail);
            gameStage.addChild(tempNail);
        }
    }
    gameStage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
    gameStage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickToHit);
}
```

Here's the code I used to remove the nails. But nothing happens after this code. The nails are still there.

```
for (var j:int = nailList.length; j >= 0; j--)
{   
    removeNails(j);
    trace("Remove Nail");
}
function removeNails(idx:int)
{
    gameStage.removeChild(nailList[idx]);
    nailList.splice(idx,0);
}
```

I want to remove the `MovieClip` so that I can restart the game and add new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Valid array index range is from `0` to `length - 1`. You are trying to call `removeChild` with  `nailList[nailList.length]` which is invalid and `removeChild` should fire an error. You need to change the initial value of `j` to `nailList.length - 1`.

```
for (var j:int = nailList.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                                 ^^^
```

Another problem is (as pointed in the comment) the second parameter of `splice` is delete count. So you need to use 1 instead of 0.

```
nailList.splice(idx, 1);
                     ^
```

Comment: There is another smaller mistake in the code, splicing should be done for 1 object instead of 0 in his code.

Comment: Thank you so much i fixed it already and this did the trick. Im quite new in actionscript so i cant get a hold of some of its logic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice` to remove the child of an array.

```
arrName.splice(2,1);
```

Hope it will help.